# Import Score from myanimelist.net into google sheets

Tags: html, css, xpath, google-sheets

What would I need to type into google sheets to import the score "8.40" from this url (https://myanimelist.net/anime/31240/Re_Zero_kara_Hajimeru_Isekai_Seikatsu)? I would also like to know how to import the people "2414" and score "5" for the 4 reviews from the same url.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to find a solution for yourself and then post a more specific question. These types of "How to do X" questions are not really welcome here. To get you started though, you may want to look at unofficial myanimelist APIs that do just that, e.g. Jikan.moe https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/31240 which gives a JSON with all data

https://jikan.moe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get you started with what you should be contributing:

```
 =importxml("https://myanimelist.net/anime/31240/Re_Zero_kara_Hajimeru_Isekai_Seikatsu","//div[@class='fl-l score']")
```